# Freeform: disallow hyperlinks in message field

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace, spam

`Craft CMS: 3.5.x`
`Freeform Lite: 3.11.3`

Is there a way to flag submissions as spam (or block altogether) when the message field contains hyperlinks?

Answer (score 1):

Yeh - under `Settings -> Spam Settings` you'll find `Block Keywords`:

[image]

Adding `http://*` and `https://*` should work.

If you get hit with the same spammers throw their domain in there and it should effectively block 'em.

As an aside, the honeypot (and/or) Captcha is pretty effective too since most of the form submissions that contain URLs are garbage.

Comment: Thank you RiiterKnight! I will try adding this pattern to the "block keywords" field 

Comment: @RogerGlenn: excellent let me know if it works for you, and if so, mark this as the accepted answer if it helped.